# Mounted hdd drive all of a sudden will not allow writing

Tags: mount, hard-disk, write

I have a system with TVHeadend installed on Ubuntu for 4 years and it worked perfect with recording shows and rewind live tv. But all of a sudden, when I try to record shows, the shows are not recorded. I record the shows on a mounted hdd drive and now I try to create a file there, I am not allowed. Either with VI or touch, but only I can see it write protected filesystem. Last week I rebooted the whole system and then everything worked. But yesterday, I had a show for recording it didnt record and now I can't write anything to the drive.

This is what I have in fstab file:

```
/dev/sdb1       /mnt/VIDEO_RECORDING    ext4    rw      0       2
```

When I use ll on the directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 aug 14 04:03 VIDEO_RECORDING/
```

Of course I have googled and seen different solutions like add the user of TVHeadend(hts) to the group that my user is in, I have tried do add the TVHeadend user to have write rights. Like:

```
sudo chow hts:hts /mnt/VIDEO_RECORDING/

sudo usermod -a -G my_user hts
```

I checked the kern.log which was in the answer and I got this:

```
Aug 16 04:09:40 ubuntu kernel: [300455.727139] EXT4-fs (sdb1): error count since last fsck: 2
Aug 16 04:09:40 ubuntu kernel: [300455.727142] EXT4-fs (sdb1): initial error at time 1628906759: ext4_journal_check_start:56
Aug 16 04:09:40 ubuntu kernel: [300455.727144] EXT4-fs (sdb1): last error at time 1628906759: ext4_journal_check_start:56
Aug 17 04:11:27 ubuntu kernel: [386963.492931] EXT4-fs (sdb1): error count since last fsck: 2
Aug 17 04:11:27 ubuntu kernel: [386963.492947] EXT4-fs (sdb1): initial error at time 1628906759: ext4_journal_check_start:56
Aug 17 04:11:27 ubuntu kernel: [386963.492951] EXT4-fs (sdb1): last error at time 1628906759: ext4_journal_check_start:56
```

dmesg gives me a lot of errors it seems like.

```
[37805.202453] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 272408
[37805.202767] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 33795, lost async page write
[127433.283768] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 33795.
[127433.283819] Aborting journal on device sdb1-8.
[127433.298085] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214410.
[127433.299316] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214409.
[127433.299649] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214408.
[127433.300000] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214407.
[127433.300330] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214406.
[127433.300674] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214405.
[127433.301042] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214404.
[127433.301427] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214403.
[127433.301835] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214402.
[127433.302281] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 26214401.
[127433.302731] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 25690127.
[127433.303205] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 25690126.
[127433.303694] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 25690125.
[127433.304229] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 25690124.
[127433.304760] JBD2: Error while async write back metadata bh 25690123.
[127434.121550] EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_journal_check_start:56:
[127434.122148] Detected aborted journal
[127434.122150] EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

Is there anything I can do to save this disk?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `mount` say? What does kern.log say?

Comment: Check `dmesg` for errors. `kern.log` is distro specific.

Comment: I added some more info what you ask me.

Comment: The errors indicate a mechanical failure. It's up to you whether to continue using this HDD (you'll have to fix bad sectors) or copy your data to a new one. No one knows whether this drive is able to continue running or the number of errors will grow.

Here's a manual: https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto

Comment: thanks @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the drive have errors and I will stop using this, I mounted my nas and used that as recording storage instead and now there is no problem with this anymore. Thanks!

(even though it's sad to loose a drive)